# Problem writing aux file in relative referenced directory

Tags: pdftex, miktex, input, auxiliary-files, import

In the question [Problem writing aux file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575120/problem-writing-aux-fileI) asked about the problems I encountered due to an update of my MiKTeX distribution, but didn't take the time (at that moment) to create a MWE, so it didn't attract much response.

I have the directory structure:

- main

  - manual.tex
- group

  - group__group2.tex
  - refman_doc.tex

**manual.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\subinputfrom{../group}{refman_doc}
\end{document}
```

**group__group2.tex**

```
\hypertarget{group__group2}{}{The Second Group}
```

**refman_doc.tex**

```
{Module Documentation}
\include{group__group2}
```

When running in the directory `main` the command `pdflatex manual.tex` I get the error:

```
...
(../group/../group/refman_doc.tex [1{C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdf
tex/config/pdftex.map}]
! I can't write on file `../group//group__group2.aux'.
\@include ...mmediate \openout \@partaux "#1.aux"
                                                  \immediate \write \@partau...
l.2 \include{group__group2}

Please type another output file name:
```

but in a non interactive mode (the usual way to run. i.e. with `\batchmode`) one doesn't get an opportunity to specify the file and the generation crashes.

As written in the original question adding options like `-shell-escape` and / or `-enable-write18` didn't help.

Is theer a solution for this problem?

Comment: as I already wrote in a comment to your previous question: you can't write a file in a parent directory. For security reason you can only write files in the current directory and its subfolders. If your current directory is `main` you are going *up* into the parent and then down into another folder, and this will not work with \include which tries to create an aux-file there. Use \input if you want such a layout.

Comment: Strange that this did work till my last update (Yesterday) and before that the update was a couple of months ago. Also a bit strange that the options `-shell-escape` and / or `-enable-write18` have no effect. I'm not sure that I can use `\input` here due to the fact that the the included file again includes (independent automatically generated) files from that same directory.

Comment: You can/should  edit the existing question to add clarifications rather than open a new duplicate question.

Comment: shell-escape and write18 would not affect file permissions, they are about running commands.

Comment: You _can_  `\input` a file that uses `\include` but you can not `\include` one as includes can not be nested.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Pity you changed this question as it gives better details than the old question, but alas I added the information to the original question (with some new insights) hopefully you can give a solution for the problem / reason why it worked in the recent past and now it doesn't.

Comment: @albert  you could delete the first and re-open this one if that is easier.  I do not see how writing to a path starting `../` could ever have worked (with texlive there is a highly discouraged option to turn off that security check) with miktex there may be, I have never used miktex so I can not say, it would be unlikely that you had that set without knowing though.

Comment: When I use texlive (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Cygwin)_) I have no problem, so I might have this option enabled / Cygwin might have enabled it automatically but I don't know as I don't know the name of the option, so I cannot search for it either (to get a confirmation).

Comment: I have cygwin texlive I can check later, look in texmf.cnf openout_any = p  (paranoid) is the default

Comment: I found the texmf.cnf on Cygwin (/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf) and here the setting is `openout_any = p` so this should give the same effect as under MiKTeX, but it doesn't (I just tested it with the small example and a group__group2.aux is created in the main directory).